# Dataweave exception handling

Tags: dataweave

I have a requirement in `dataweave` where I iterate a fixed length file and transform the message into a collection of java object.  However, an exception in one of the lines stops the flow execution.  I need to log the exception and continue processing the other lines.  I'm new to mule soft and I could not fine any documentation to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the input is not corrected/ not changed, the exception will occur.
You can split the file in parts/lines and pass the collection of lines to batch processing scope.
This way you have an option to process the remaining part of the input even if any error is occurring.

Comment: Look at using a splitter -> dataweave -> aggregator

Answer (score 0):

You need to know whether its a system exception or application exception. It would be difficult to catch system exceptions but application exceptions can be caught and handled in either exception handling or if you know any particular record types giving these exception you may skip these records using either filter or when condition of dataweave.

For more on Mule exception handling please check below link.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/error-handling